# Defining and using a Global Generic List in WCF Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am sending a few separate messages from an asp.net site to my WCF server.

These messages are coming through individually, and I need the server to pick them up, and 'stitch' them together.

What I am trying to do is put those methods in a global List, then using that list in a different class to do my bidding.

So far I have...

`variables.cs`

```
class variables
{
    public static List<string> MessageStitches { get; set; } 
}
```

`Program.cs`

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(node))
{
    variables.MessageStitches.Add(node);
}
```

But I am getting this error:

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Can anyone see where I am going wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: As a side note, classes in C# should start with a capital letter by convention.

Comment: I know. I was hastey in the creation, and overlooked that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set the `variables.MessageStitches` property to be a new list.

You have several options, but the best option for you is almost certainly 1 or 2.

1 - Assign a new list in the constructor of `variables`. However, as your list is static, this will not actually help you, as you may not have instantiated your `variables` class, and so your constructor will not have run. You can have a [static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) though:

```
class variables
{
    public static List<string> MessageStitches { get; set; } 

    // Static constructor
    static variables()
    {
        MessageStitches = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

2 - Don't use auto-properties. Instead, have a [backing field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173118.aspx) for your property, which is assigned a value at initialisation:

```
public class variables
{
    private static List<string> messageStitches = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> MessageStitches 
    { 
        get
        {
            return messageStitches;
        }
        set
        {
            messageStitches = value;
        } 
    }
```

3 - Check the list before using to ensure it's not null and, if it is, assign a new list then. Again, this will not be threadsafe, unless you take steps to make it so (e.g. by entering a [critical section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section))

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(node))
{
    if (variables.MessageStitches == null)
    {
        variables.MessageStitches = new List<string>();
    }
    variables.MessageStitches.Add(node);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a constructor in Variable.cs like:

```
public variables()
{
  MessageStitches = new List<string>();
}
```

or you can do like this :

```
variables.MessageStitches = new List<string>();
variables.MessageStitches.Add(node);
```